# JDBC Assertion Error: Number of messages received should be less than number of messages sent

Tags: java, android, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL database in Android using JDBC. After following the relevant tutorials, I've been met with an `Assertion Error: numMsgsRcvd:1 should be less than numMsgsSent:1`. Below is the code snippet and error trace. I'm not sure where to go from here, and how to add to the number of messages sent or reduce the number received, or whether this is just hiding a different issue.

```
public class Campus extends AsyncTask<Connection, Integer, Long> {

    public Connection connection;
    private String connectionString;

    public Campus(String conn) {
        connectionString = conn;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Connection... connections) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Long.valueOf(100);
    }
}

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: numMsgsRcvd:1 should be less than numMsgsSent:1
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6601)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.nextPacket(IOBuffer.java:6567)
        ...
        at uol.co4224.campusfood.Campus.doInBackground(Campus.java:22)
        at uol.co4224.campusfood.Campus.doInBackground(Campus.java:9)
```

Comment: FYI: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Is there a tutorial or guide that may be helpful for implementing this?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow. You can use your favorite search engine to find tutorials for your database on your OS platform about creating web service / REST APIs.